# Make Cypress only allow stubbed routes / stub every request

Tags: cypress

I want my Cypress test to fail if a XHR request is made that is not stubbed using `cy.route()`, so I can be sure I have stubbed every request. This will make sure my app isn't hitting the actual server. This way if everything is stubbed, I won't require my server to be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Pass the `force404` option to `cy.server`:

```js
 cy.server({force404: true})
    cy.route('**/user/jake', {user:{name:'Jake'})
    cy.visit('/')
    // your test code here
```

Then any XHR request to `/user/jake` will work, but `/user/jane` and `/login` for example, will `404`